# How to authenticate against visualstudio.com?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, azure-devops

I would like to do the same thing shown in this [Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Tutorials/Authenticating-a-Windows-Azure-Web-Site-against-an-Office-365-Domain) Video (Authentication) but with visualstudio.com accounts instead of Office 365. Does that mean I need to back up my visualstudio.com account with a Azure AD and then use that Azure AD for my Web Application SSO? Doesn't visualstudio.com come with it's own Azure AD already just like Office 365?

Note that my visualstudio.com account already have users in it and would like to continue allowing them to login to my web application. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

(I asked this question in [MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9a17e8fa-85a0-4a6b-aca7-b6a95f08271c/how-to-authenticate-against-visualstudiocom?forum=TFService) but no one has really answered it)

Karlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to achieve this feature, your account need to be backed by a Microsoft Azure Active Directory. [Click this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/setup/assign-licenses-to-users-vs#ConnectedDirectory) to see how to check if your account is backed by AAD or not.